# What is stored in the leaf node of clustered index

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, b-tree, clustered-index

I understand that in the leaf node of clustered index the table record is stored together with say primary key.

But I found some articles stated that primary key is stored with block address of real record instead of real table record.

Could you tell me which is correct?

(1)store block address
[image]

(2)store real data
[image]

Comment: From what I understand, the index for `clustered` is stored in the table file. If not, a separate index file is created. (they give MyISAM as an example)

Comment: Hi @bato3 MyISAM does not have clustered index

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to write. That MyISAM is not `clustered` and a separate file for the index was always created there. I propose to do an experiment and see if it creates an additional file for InnoDB. `CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (id)`

Comment: This question can probably find better answers at dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful what you read.  Be sure the article talks about "MySQL" and its main 'engine' "InnoDB".

> primary key is stored with block address of real record instead of real table record.

Several entire rows are stored in each leaf node (block) of the data's B+Tree.  That BTree is ordered by the `PRIMARY KEY`, which is (obviously) part of the row.

The only "block addresses" are the links you have in both of your diagrams.

I vote for your number 2 diagram, with these provisos:

- There is a 4-column row with id=6 and other columns of James, 37, LA.
- The row with id=15 is not fully shown.  That is, you left out the other 3 columns.

A "block" is 16KB and can hold between 1 and several hundred rows, depending on

- size of rows,
- whether rows have been deleted, leaving 'free' space,
- etc.

(100 rows per block for either data or index is a simple Rule of Thumb.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I followed the way to find the answer in the context of mysql and innodb.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of mysql and innodb, from the mysql official page
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-index-types.html

> Each InnoDB table has a special index called the clustered index that stores row data.

> If a table is large, the clustered index architecture often saves a disk I/O operation when compared to storage organizations that store row data using a different page from the index record.

Based on above facts, especially number 2, I believe #2 is the correct one. From my side the reasons are
(1)save one time I/O.
If leaf node save the page address, there will be one more time of I/O to fetch the record.

(2)more maintainability.
If page split happened and the leaf node save the page address only, there will be a lot of trouble for clustered index to update the record data page address.

However, the reason why I think #1 has points is that saving address only is cheaper than saving whole row of record data and thus store more index.

Comment: There are a few queries that would be performed faster with #1.  But (in my experience) those cases are a minority.  That is, InnoDB made the 'right' design decision.